# Mod lines in Java code

Tags: java, version-control

Often in C code (and some other languages as well) I have seen a section in the top-level comments for mod lines. These include the date a modification to the file was made, the user who made the modification, and a brief description of what was changed.

I have not yet seen an equivalent of this in Java. I think this information is useful, especially when trying to track down bugs in code I did not write. Is this because Java code is often under version control, or are there other reasons? Are there any suggestions as to how to include the information in the code file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no reason to have those useless comments in any source file. Its just reinventing version control extremely poorly.

Comment: What if, for whatever reason, the code cannot be placed under version control?

Comment: @Michael:  There is no such reason.  You can always use version control, period.  And if you aren't, and are using those mod lines, you're still using version control.  You're just using crappy version control.

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen Java files with a header including the original date created and the author, but not "mod lines". Version control would make that rather superfluous, as it tracks changes on a per-line basis by user.

As for why they're used in C, perhaps it's an old custom from before the days of VC.

Answer (score 0):

Often in Java I see these types of lines, but it's not entered manually.  Most VCSs can tag any text file with that data, as long as a template is left in the file to insert that information into.

For instance, in the VCS I use, if I include `$Id: ... $` anywhere in the file, the `...` will be replaced with the file name, version number, last editor, edit date, etc.

Some people think they're useless in light of VCSs (which store all of that information), but I don't.  It's quick access to that information which you would have to mine for (or at least leave your file editor) by going through the VCS.

**Edit**: By the way, nobody's highlighted my main reason for disliking them (remember, I said they're not useless, not that I like them).  I hate that they add textual changes to the file at each checkin.  You either need a highly configurable diff client to ignore those changes, or you're faced with boilerplate changes at each revision which make it more cumbersome to see what actually changed.

Comment: Any IDE worth using makes this information *and much more* accessible without significant effort. Having it in the source code is pointless noise.

Comment: @Peter as does any VCS itself :)

Comment: @Mark: Where to you typically put that template? Also, does that only include the last editor, or a list of them?

Comment: @Peter: that's not my experience.  IDEs can do a good job, but often don't.  I've certainly not found them to make that information *more* accessible than just looking at the top of the file.  But it's also for the times when you're not in the full-fledged IDE at the moment.  Maybe you're making a quick edit in vim.  Maybe you're using your favourite diff tool at that moment.

Comment: @mathepic: The point is, going to the VCS is usually more work than it's worth.

Comment: @Michael: usually at the very top of the file or in the class javadoc.  Our company's header just lists the most current author.  I haven't seen ones that have a list of editors, but that might be possible.

Comment: @Mark Peters Typing `git blame <file>` is no work at all and gives a lot more information. Similarly with `git log <file>`.

Comment: @mathepic: It's exactly "9 characters of typing plus the name of the file" amount of work.  Don't say it's no work at all when that's an obvious lie.  Going to the top of my file is two keystrokes at the most (gg or CTRL-Home)

Comment: @Mark Peters and if you can touch type decently the difference is virtually indistinguishable. If you can't type `git blame <file>`, something is wrong... And thats without considering putting a macro into your text editor.